# How do you achieve the 'Know Thy Enemy ' achievement in CIV V?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

It says you must 'Consult the Oracle 2 times in a single game', but I haven't any idea what that means!

Comment: I don't know for sure, and can't find anything on the web yet, but I suspect it's something to do with the new "Wonders of the Ancient World Scenario Pack" DLC that has just been released...

Comment: I wonder if it's something like build the Oracle, lose control of it, then regain control of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=437251) forum, you can't get the achievement in a normal game; you need to play the "Wonders of the Ancient World Scenario Pack DLC".